# StatefulBuilder's setState function not changing the color of IconButton

Tags: flutter, setstate

I'm making an Instagram clone app and I'm trying to use `StatefulBuilder` but the `setState`
function of the builder does not change the color of the `Container` wrapped in `GestureDetector` ( `onTap` function ).

```
StatefulBuilder(
                        builder: (context, setState) {
                          var color = Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 1);
                          return Flexible(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  color = Color.fromRGBO(0, 149, 246, 1);
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                height: 30,
                                // width: double.infinity,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                    color: color),
                                child: const Text('Follow'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
```

I want the `Follow` button to change it's color but I don't want to use the `setState` of the `Stateful Widget` as I don't want to rebuild the whole screen.
Am I using `StatefulBuilder` incorrectly or is there any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var color = Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 1);
```

above line should be outside of `StatefulBuilder`

Comment: Oh my god that was extremely stupid of me... I can't thank you enough... Thanksss.

Answer (score 1):

You define your `color` variable inside your `StatefulBuilder`, and every time you call `setState` it resets this value and set the default value to it, you need to define it out of `StatefulBuilder`, like this:

```
var color = Color.fromRGBO(38, 38, 38, 1);

StatefulBuilder(
   builder: (context, setState) {
       return Flexible(
    ...
)
```